# How to know the previous event handled in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

on page load i have shown data from database onto a gridview(with edit and delete option). I also have a search button on the page. when i click on search the searched data should be visible in the gridview, which is working fine. But when i click on delete link after search it does not take the searched row. The page postsback after clicking on delete. I need to check the event performed prior to event performed on gridview. How to do that?? I hope that the issue is clear.. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: _"I hope that the issue is clear"_ Nope. You might want to show us some code.

Comment: Are you familiar with the built-in ASP.Net tracing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfbfw58f(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load occurs before RowCommand, are you only binding grid if(!IsPostBack) ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid(searchText.Text);
}

protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Delete":
            DeleteRow(e.Row.CommandArgument);
            break;
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    //GridView binding business logic.
}

private void BindGrid(String searchTerm)
{
    //GridView binding logic with searchTerm.
}

private void DeleteRow(String commandArg)
{
    //Convert command arg to ID or whatever and delete data.
}
```